# При добавлении CNAME выходит ошибка Nginx

Tags: nginx, сервер, dns, vesta, cname

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении CNAME и попытке перехода по нему выбивает стартовую Nginx страницу.
Vesta

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в `server_name` все домены, по которым будет доступен сайт, в том числе CNAME (в примере это `www.site.ru`):

```
server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
```

После чего проверить и перечитать конфиг:

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx reload
```